# Tire moves when brakes are applied, car slides/jaunts sideways when you accelerate or apply the brakes

Tags: brakes, tires, steering, frontend

My 2011 HHR failed inspection because when the brakes are applied the drivers side tire moves back and forth, front to back movement.  When I purchased it there was an issue that I didn't think was as bad as the tire movement appears to be. When you accelerate, or hit the brakes the care has a slight sideways jaunt or slide if you will. Obviously these two are related. Im just needing a little direction so I can troubleshoot not change parts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like a bearing is bad causing too much play. Have a good reviewed mechanic do a diagnosis, doing it yourself will be a hassle.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! I see you've posted two answers telling people to "go see a mechanic". For the most part, people don't come here to get told to go to a mechanic, so these types of answers are a waste of space. A real answer will give the OP the information they need, where they can decide for themselves if it is something they can fix or if they'll need to go to a mechanic. Some people just want to know what's going on, so they can understand it before they go to a mechanic. Whichever it is, I hope you can help by providing rich & full answers. We're here to help

Comment: well in all fairness I'm an electrician and the forums/pages I'm on that deal with electrical i have on more than one occasion answered a troubleshooting question with "call a qualified electrician". I'm definitly gonna do that just to get a professional opinion. And seeing as I have some spare time due to the entire globe deciding status quo was so yesterday I'm gonna try and do it myself for no other reason than Epstien didn't commit suicide

Comment: @Damian so you have found the issue, can you tell us what it was...

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the suspension joints as a failed bush can allow for the movement you describe.

Inspect the tire tread as a failed bush can cause rapid tire wear on the inside or outside edges.

I have just replaced all of the rear suspension on my car as one bush had failed after 15 years - logic being the others were likely to fail soon. Result is a car that has no squeaks, rattles or clonks and handles like new.